# javascript double loop `for` two array

Tags: javascript

Here is my current code:

```
let total = 4;
let total_attr = 2;

for (let i = 0; i < total; ++i) {

    let    name = result.Item[i].attr[0].Name[0],
        value = result.Item[i].attr[0].Value[0]

    let    name2 = result.Item[i].attr[1].Name[0],
        value2 = result.Item[i].attr[1].Value[0]

    let return_value = [{
        [name]: value,
        [name2]: value2
    }];

    result.push( function() {return {return_value};} );
}
```

Right now I'm defining `.attr[0]` manually, and I'd like to make it loop like `.attr[k]` this, and cant figure out? thanks.

my result:

```
        "return_value": [{
                "Size": "5",
                "Color": "Green"}
        ]
        "return_value": [{
                "Size": "8",
                "Color": "Green"}
        ]
        "return_value": [{
                "Size": "5",
                "Color": "Pink"}
        ]
        "return_value": [{
                "Size": "8",
                "Color": "Pink"}
        ]
```

sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by _make it inside the loop_?

Comment: Show us what `result` looks like and what the desired result is. Also fix the typo with the `..`.

Comment: What does `result` like before you start looping through it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made several assumptions here, but I'd imagine this is probably close to what you're after:

```
// results array
let result = [];

// for each item in results.Item[] array
for (let i = 0; i < result.Item.length; i++) {
    let item = result.Item[i];

    // for each item results.Item[i].attr[] array
    for (let j = 0; j < item.attr.length; j++) {
        let attr = item.attr[j];

        result.push({
            // NB: are these definitely array references?

            // if not, just use:
            // name: attr.Name,
            // value: attr.Value

            name: attr.Name[0],
            value: attr.Value[0]            
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh? A guess. The first loop goes through the initial array. The second loop goes through the secondary array within each object. The secondary loop is currently using the name array for the length.

```
var return_value;
var array = [{
    name: ['jack', 'david'],
    value: [1,2]
  },
  {
    name: ['leo', 'adam'],
    value: [1,2]
  }
]

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     for(var j = 0; j < array[i].name.length; j++ ) {
        return_value.push({
            name: array[i].name[j];
            value: array[i].value[j]
        })
     }
}
```